# Creating User Groups on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a rails application in which a user can create a group, add contacts, add a contact to that group and subsequently broadcast information out to the users to a group they have created.

I'm at the third stage where I'm now trying to allow the logged in user to add a contact to the group.

I have three models for many to many relationships:

```
class UserGroups < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end
```

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user

  has_many: :user_groups
  has_many: :users, through: :user_groups

  validates :title, presence: true

end
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_one_attached :avatar

  has_many :groups, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :user_groups
  has_many :users, through: :user_groups

  before_create :set_circleid
  has_many :contactships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :contacts, -> { where contactships: { status: :accepted }}, through: :contactships
  has_many :requested_contacts, -> { where contactships: { status: :requested }}, through: :contactships, source: :contact
  has_many :pending_contacts, -> { where contactships: { status: :pending }}, through: :contactships, source: :contact
  has_many :blocked_contacts, -> { where contactships: { status: :blocked }}, through: :contactships, source: :contact

  has_many :contactships_inverse, class_name: 'Contactship', foreign_key: :contact_id
  has_many :contacts_inverse, through: :contactships_inverse, source: :user

  def all_contacts
    contacts + contacts_inverse
  end

  def has_contactship?(contact)
      #return true if the user is a contact
      return true if self == contact
      contactships.map(&:contact_id).include?(contact.id)
  end

  def requested_contacts_with?(contact)
      return false if self == contact
      #we are going to map requested contacts with list of users to see if they include contact_id
      requested_contacts.map(&:id).include?(contact.id)
  end

  def pending_contacts_with?(contact)
      return false if self == contact
      pending_contacts.map(&:id).include?(contact.id)
  end

  def contacts_with?(contact)
      return false if self == contact
      contacts.map(&:id).include?(contact.id)
  end

  def contact_request(contact)
    #unless the contact is not equal to self and contactship does not already exist
    unless self == contact || Contactship.where(user: self, contact: contact).exists?
        #transaction means that if one fails they both are rolled back
        transaction do
            #for user to another user (sent request)
            Contactship.create(user: self, contact: contact, status: :pending)
            #from another user to user (recieve request)
            Contactship.create(user: contact, contact: self, status: :requested)
        end
     end

  def accept_request(contact)
      transaction do
        Contactship.find_by(user: self, contact: contact, status: [:requested])&.accepted!
        Contactship.find_by(user: contact, contact: self, status: [:pending])&.accepted!
      end
  end

  def reject_request(contact)
      transaction do
        Contactship.find_by(user: self, contact: contact)&.destroy!
        Contactship.find_by(user: contact, contact: self)&.destroy!
      end
  end
end
```

And a method within my group controller (not sure what to do here):

```
    #for adding a user to a group?
    def add_user
        #search for the group?
        @group = Group.find(params[:id])
        #add a user to that group via user_groups? How?
    end
```

schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_06_22_142356) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "active_storage_attachments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.string "record_type", null: false
    t.bigint "record_id", null: false
    t.bigint "blob_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.index ["blob_id"], name: "index_active_storage_attachments_on_blob_id"
    t.index ["record_type", "record_id", "name", "blob_id"], name: "index_active_storage_attachments_uniqueness", unique: true
  end

  create_table "active_storage_blobs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "key", null: false
    t.string "filename", null: false
    t.string "content_type"
    t.text "metadata"
    t.bigint "byte_size", null: false
    t.string "checksum", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.index ["key"], name: "index_active_storage_blobs_on_key", unique: true
  end

  create_table "groups", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_groups_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "contactships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.bigint "contact_id"
    t.integer "status", limit: 2, default: 0
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["contact_id"], name: "index_contactships_on_contact_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_contactships_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "description"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.string "thought"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "user_groups", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.bigint "group_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["group_id"], name: "index_user_groups_on_group_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_user_groups_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "groupid"
    t.text "bio"
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "active_storage_attachments", "active_storage_blobs", column: "blob_id"
  add_foreign_key "groups", "users"
  add_foreign_key "comments", "users"
  add_foreign_key "user_groups", "groups"
  add_foreign_key "user_groups", "users"
end
```

How would I go about developing the method so I can successfully add a contact to a group in the console? I'm confused particularly about the method to make that happen, especially because the contacts are not their own model but part of the user model.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share your schema.rb / database schema as well.

Comment: Sure - placed it above!

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```rb
group = Group.find(params[:id])
contact = User.find(params[:user_id])
UserGroups.create(user: contact, group: group)
```

### Naming

You already mention the term `contacts` in your question, maybe consider naming your association like this. You can specify a `class_name` attribute to let Rails know the name of the your model class if it doesn't match the association name.

```rb
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User"

  has_many: :user_groups
  has_many: :contacts, through: :user_groups, class_name: "User"

  validates :title, presence: true
```

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to

### has_many through vs. has_and_belongs_to

You should think also if you really need the `UserGroups` model or use a `has_and_belongs_to` association, see from the Rails guide

> The simplest rule of thumb is that you should set up a has_many :through relationship if you need to work with the relationship model as an independent entity. If you don't need to do anything with the relationship model, it may be simpler to set up a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship (though you'll need to remember to create the joining table in the database).

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many

Comment: Interesting about the relationship. So if the group was only visible to the user - I guess it wouldn't need the third entity?

Comment: What do you mean with visible? As stated in the quote, the main difference is if you need to put logic into the `UserGroups` model or not. If it's simply just a join model / table, you don't need to create it and can use a `has_and_belongs_to` relationship and delete the `UserGroups` model. You would still need the table though.

Comment: Meaning that the group is individual to the user, it contains contacts but is not shared with other contacts. On what you're saying though I think it's right, there would not need to be any logic in ```UserGroups```

Comment: If a group has many contact and is shared between users than your `belongs_to :user` also needs to be a `has_and_belongs_to` relationship.